# How to recursively split a string in half and then split the smaller strings in Java

Tags: java

on my recent midterm I had a question where I was told to split a big string into 2 equal small and split the smaller strings into halves again. I know it has to be done recursively for this question but I am not aware of how to apply it to Java code.

Any help would be great, Thank you.

```
public class Question7a {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strings = "aaaa bbbb cccc dddd";
    Question7a question7a = new Question7a();
    question7a.splitString(strings);
}

public void splitString(String words){
        int m = words.length() / 2; //gets the middle length of the string to split there.
        for (int i=0; i < m; i++) {
        String[] halves = {words.substring(0, m), words.substring(m)};
        System.out.println(halves[0]); //first half of the string
        System.out.println(halves[1]); //second part
            if(halves[0].equals(true)){
                int m2 = halves.length/2; //Intent was to get the middle of the new half.
                halves[0] = {hal.substring(0, m2), words.substring(m2)};
                halves[1] = {words.substring(0, m2), words.substring(m2)};
                System.out.println(halves[0]);
                System.out.println(halves[1]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Null");
    }
}
```

}

Kind of want a output to something like:

```
"aaaa bbbb"      cccc  dddd
   |                |
   |                |
"aaaa" "bbbb"    cccc  dddd
   |      |
   |      |  
"aa" "aa" "bb" "bb"
```

and similar (not sure if this is the right way to look at it) for the other half.

Comment: It's a good idea to share the code you currently have so far, so that others can guide you in the exact places you might have questions. Asking the way you did might lead others to think you're just expecting someone to do your homework for you, and will lead to many downvotes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking a question regarding homework, please show some effort and add code that you tried and explain where you failed. People here aren't likely to do all of your homework for you.

Comment: sorry about that i updated it with the code, new to this but should of thought about that beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Stack;
class Hackerearth{
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Stack<String> st = new Stack<>();
        String str = "aaaa bbbb cccc dddd";
        st.push(str);
        split(st);
    }

    public static void split(Stack<String> st){
        while(!st.empty()){
            String s = st.pop();
            if(s.length() == 1){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            else{
                int mid = s.length() / 2;
                String first = s.substring(0, mid);
                String second = s.substring(mid, s.length());
                st.push(second);
                st.push(first);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use Stack in Java.util package.. It has push and pop methods predefined to add and remove items.. [Stack Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was wondering if I can use it for my approach I placed above. Sorry I didnt add it earlier.